# mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter to be string

Tags: php, mysqli

I already uploaded my page in 000webhost.com, fixed the connections but got problem with my admin page. It has this error.

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/a8431834/public_html/admin_area/login.php on line 36

Below is my code.

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/login_style.css" media="all" /> 

</head>
<body>
<div class="login">
<h2 style="color:white; text-align:center;"><?php echo @$_GET['not_admin']; ?></h2>


<h2 style="color:white; text-align:center;"><?php echo @$_GET['logged_out']; ?></h2>

<h1>Admin Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" name="login">Login</button>
</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
<?php 

include("includes/db.php"); 

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

$sel_user = "select * from admins where user_email='$email' AND user_pass='$pass'";

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user); 

 $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user); 

if($check_user==1){

$_SESSION['user_email']=$email; 

echo "<script>window.open('index.php?logged_in=You have successfully Logged in!','_self')</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script>alert('Password or Email is wrong, try again!')</script>";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing `mysql` with `mysqli`. The two APIs are different.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is you are mixing the deprecated `mysql_` along with the `mysqli_*` so instead of using `mysql_real_escape_string` use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
```

and you can learn more about [mysqli_real_escape_string() on PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

And beware of using the deprecated version, if you have done anywhere else first of all update those functions with the new one's